# Trying to understand instance variables in python

Tags: python-2.7, variables, instance-variables

I am trying to create an instance variable in one of my methods and call it in another. I come from a ruby background where you can just do @test = 'this is test'. I have been reading up and I am still a bit confused how I can accomplish the same thing in python. Is the **init** method necessary? Can I just create an instance variable within my create_test method and call it? In the project I am working on I am doing a lot of calculations in one method that I want to store as variables to use later. Below is a simplified version of where I'm at.

```
class ThisTest():
test = ''

def __init__(self):
    self.test = self.test

def create_test(self):
    self.test = 'this is test'

def puts_test(self):
    print self.test


run = ThisTest()
run.puts_test()
```

This outputs ''. Where I want to declare this variable in create_test. Maybe in python I don't want to use an instance variable for this, I am approaching this the wrong way. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'self' variable refers to the instance. In your example, `test` is a class variable, whereas what you want is probably to set `self.whatever`  in your calculation method.

```
In [38]: class Test(object):
   ....:     def modify_state(self):
   ....:         self.ponk = "ponk"
   ....:         self.blonk = "splonk"
   ....:

In [39]: a = Test()

In [40]: a.ponk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-00b6c3f2ca26> in <module>()
----> 1 a.ponk

AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'ponk'

In [41]: a.modify_state()

In [42]: a.ponk
Out[42]: 'ponk'
```

`__init__` is called when an instance is first created and gives you a chance to set up initial state on the instance.

The difference between inherited class variables and proper instance variables might be visible here:

```
In [43]: Test.ponk = "blork"

In [44]: a = Test()

In [45]: a.ponk is Test.ponk
Out[45]: True

In [46]: a.modify_state()

In [47]: a.ponk is Test.ponk
Out[47]: False
```

In hindsight, 'ponk' and 'blonk' and 'splork' are probably very shitty names for this example. Sorry.